# Google Streetview API - Get Panorama JPG

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is there a way for me to get a complete 360 panorama image (such as a jpg) from a location in Streetview? Basically, I want to do custom presentation of the image and want to download the whole thing at once rather than using the Streetview window and it's controls.

There is a section in the Google Documentation for Panoramas but they don't explain how to get a streetview 360 image. Instead, they use the streetview window, which I don't want to do.

**EDIT**
I should clarify that I'm not trying to build my own streetviewer. I just want the entire image so that I can present it to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a static image, check the [Google Street View Image API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/streetview/), you can get panos with a field of view (`fov`) up to 120 deg. However, it seems to me you jus to create your own Street View viewer re-using Google's images... which is against the [Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).

Comment: Could you please point to the specific clause that says this is disallowed? Because the API documentation seems to say it's ok. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html#StreetViewPanoramas

Comment: Also, I would like a static image of the entire 360 degree field. However, my experiments has lead to show me that in the image api the pitch varies too much for me to construct a 360 field using (120 degree chunks) which doesn't seem to be an issue for regular streetview.

Comment: Also this seems to be possible: http://www.flickr.com/photos/swilsonmc/4041171489/

Comment: If you're after _ create your own `StreetViewPanorama` object_, LGTM. Still I think you're not supposed to build a 360 field using the Street View Image API and that video is clearly not compliant with the Terms of Use. Nothing is so by piecing tiles together or removing the logos and attribution!

Comment: This one works more the way I want it to: http://www.flickr.com/photos/swilsonmc/2543157901/

Also I looked at the images; they are all watermarked.

Comment: I'm no lawyer but I suspect stitching tiles on your own (out of the API) is against point 10.1.1.(a) _No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service. You must not access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service_. I wouldn't do that in a production app. Just saying.

Comment: 10.1.1. General Restrictions. 
(a) No Access to Maps API(s) **except through the Service**. You must not access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service, or through other explicitly authorized means Google may designate. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).


**Streetview Service**: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview.html

Comment: That's right, as long as you use the Streetview Service as documented, I think you'll be OK. However, those examples you've linked, are totally not ;)

Answer (score 5):

When you're in street-view of google maps with your desired zoom open Developer Tools (chrome: `ctrl` + `shift` + `I`).

Under `resources` open `frames` -> `data` -> `images`. Scroll down to `cbk`.

There will probably be a lot of them. Find one that is a single tile of your current location. Right click and open in a new tab.

In the address bar find the part that says `output=tile&x=1&y=2&zoom=4` or whatever values they may be.

`x=_&y=_` is the name of the tile. To get all the tiles you'll need to go through every variation of `x` and `y` and reload the page and save the image each time.

At `zoom=3`, `x` goes from 0 to 6 and `y` goes from 0 to 3 for a total of 28 tiles.

At `zoom=4`, `x` goes from 0 to 12 and `y` goes from 0 to 6 for a total of 91 tiles.